# Can a Tap Gesture Recognizer in IB be used on a UILabel and/or UIImageView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an xib with a single UIView containing a bunch of images and labels. If I drag a Tap Gesture Recognizer onto the parent view, it works well, but I need to add code to determine the position of the tap so I can respond properly to the label tapped.

I thought it would be a lot easier if I could instead drag Gesture Recognizers to each label and/or image and wire IBActions to each where I respond respond appropriately. Unfortunately I cannot get this to work. I can only get the delegate methods to execute from the parent view.

What I did was drag a Tap Gesture Recognizer to a label, then wired the view controller as the TGR's delegate, and wired an IBAction method to handle the tap. In addition to using the IBAction method I tried without succes assigning the target and action method in the gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:gestureRecognizer delegate method.

Shouldn't this work, or am I just wishfully thinking?

Thanks for any help.

John

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On UIImages and UILabels, `userInteractionEnabled` is set to NO by default.  You can use a gesture recognizer with both of them, but first you have to reset this property.

In Interface Builder or Storyboard, on the label or the image, check the box for userInteractionEnabled.

Or, in code, just do as follows (Objective-C):

```
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
myImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

(Swift):

```
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
myImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Curiously, checking the box in IB worked for the label but for the image the only way I could get it to work was to do it in code.

Comment: I think I figured out why the difference. If you use the same IBAction for more than 1 object and check the userInteractionEnabled check box for both, only the first one checked appears to work. The second one, or both have to be done in code.

Comment: Glad you worked it out.  That's odd that about an IBAction affecting the userInteractionEnabled check box in that way; maybe something else is going on.  But, I never finish finding all the quirks in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  I was pulling my hair out, and the solution was so simple.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, in Xcode 7 Interface Builder, there are two checkboxes for "User interaction enabled". One is in the Identity Inspector (icon looks like an ID card), and one is in the Attributes Inspector (icon is a pentagon and looks like a slider thumb). The one you need checked is in the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: do it better from the storyboard - Attributes Inspector, check User Interaction enabled.. no coding required!